# Sounds natural?

Tags: word-usage

Does the following sentence sound natural?

> The quality of this olive oil is so high that after tasting it, you
> will consider all **the** olive oils you previously **have had**
> olive-flavor water or something (!) rather than genuine olive oil.

I have marked the words that I was most uncertain about in bold. Two specific questions:

1- Is the definite article "the" necessary before "olive oils you previously ..."?

2- Which one is more appropriate: "olive oils you previously have had" or "olive oils you previously had"?

Answer (score 1):

1. The definite article is not required. You can say:

> all the olive oils

> all olive oils

2. Any of these would be acceptable. Note that I added **as** at the end. I think it's necessary to sound natural and for clarity.

> all [the] olive oil you've previously had as
>
> all [the] olive oil you have previously had as
>
> all [the] olive oil you previously had as

I believe that American speakers favor the last example, while non-American English speakers favor the other two.

I would also put a comma after something, but it might not be required.

> as olive-flavor water or something, rather than genuine olive oil.

Comment: Why is "as" required? "To consider" can take an object complement.